# detecting user touch on UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I basically wanted to detect when a user scrolls and removes his finger from the screen. What is the easiast for this? I was thinking of using:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
    NSLog(@"TOUCH ENDED");
}
```

but I put this in my UIViewController, but it isn't get called

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using the **UIScrollViewDelegate** function

```
(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

This gets called when the user lifts the finger after dragging the scroll view.
See here: [UIScrollViewDelegate Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate)