# how to response to touchupinside event in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a UIScrollView in the centre of the whole view which is separated in to three parts and scroll horizontally.

Users can scroll the view freely and when the finger is up, i want to set one of the three parts to show based on the contentoffset of the UIScrollView.

how could i detect the touchupinside event in the UIScrollView? I tried add UITapGestureRecognizer and override touchesEnded but it does not work.

Comment: UIScrollViewDelegate?   
from the class:
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;                                               // any offset changes
, also 
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609226/detecting-user-touch-on-uiscrollview
have a loot at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about instead using the `- scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`?

Keep in mind that just because the user has picked up their finger doesn't mean that the scrollview has stopped changing its content offset.  By utilizing the `- scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` delegate method, yo will be notified when the scroll view has come to a stop and at that point you can check the `contentOffset` and do what you need.

`- scrollViewDidScroll:` isn't a good match for what you want as it gets called even while the user's finger is still down.  If that is important to you, then use `- scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` as I mentioned above.  If you'd rather know when the finger is lifted, and don't care that the scrollview is still in transit, then you can use `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate`.